# Prometheus query duplicates values

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I ran the query below in Prometheus and I see that it works, however I have 1 pod called dummy-podX not 2 , it seems that somehow the values are being duplicated.

```
sum by (namespace,pod) (kube_pod_info{namespace="default"})


{namespace="default", pod="dummy-pod3"} 2

{namespace="default", pod="dummy-pod2"} 2
```

```
kubectl get pod -n default
NAME                                             READY   STATUS             RESTARTS         AGE
dummy-pod2                                       1/1     Running            0                3h8m
dummy-pod3                                       1/1     Running            0                3h3m
```

Have you faced this issue?, Is anybody able to advise how to adjust this?.

Comment: Could you get the result `kubectl get pod -n default `? It could helpful to understand what's going on.

Comment: @hiroyukik, I have added the output of the command you have suggested, thanks.

Comment: Thanks. In my environment, I could get the result what you may want. Could you show the result of query the `kube_pod_info{namespace="default"}` ? I wonder there could be  four records in the result.

Comment: @farp332 Is your issue resolved.Can you please share the result of the query `kube_pod_info{namespace="default"}` ?

Comment: @FariyaRahmat The issue for me was that I had 2 instances of node exporter from different Prometheus deployments in the same k8s cluster but in differents NameSpaces, so both exporters were duplicating the data and the query was displaying twice everything.

Comment: The query was displaying everything twice may be because of 2 instances of node exporter which is not required. Refer to this [link1](https://devopscube.com/node-exporter-kubernetes/) and [link2](https://www.metricfire.com/blog/how-to-deploy-prometheus-on-kubernetes/) which may help you to resolve the error.

Comment: @FariyaRahmat hey, I told what I did and how I fixed it, not point you to duplicate my own answer to build yours, I believe it is a good idea to delete your comment.

Comment: By seeing your comment it was not clear that your issue was resolved. So I posted that comment. Since your issue is resolved can you post the solution you have followed and accept it for greater visibility of the community